# while loop syntax error unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, syntax, while-loop, syntax-error

I have a syntax error with my while loop and my code is as follows

```
#! /bin/bash
# extracts pdb from mdcrd and fix number and move to one central location

filename="min_8a-"
i=1
num_structures=1000
natoms=97
folders=15



while [[ $i -le $folders ]]; do
 cd ~/new/sa/na-main/a-na-main/second/$i
 mkdir pdbfit

x=1

 while [[ $x -le $num_structures ]]; do

   ptraj ./8a-${a}.prmtop << EOF
   trajin $filename$a.mdcrd $x $x 1
   trajout pdbfit/a-2-$i.pdb pdb dumpq
 EOF
 let x=$x+1
 done

 cd pdbfit 
 mv *.* ~/pdbfit
 cd ..
 rm pdbfit

let i=$i+1
done
```

I get line 34 syntax error stating " syntax error : unexpected end of file"

as a untrained eye I have tried but failed to fix this problem so if anyone can help me with this then that will be greatful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure `EOF` is at the start of the line.

```
   ptraj ./8a-${a}.prmtop << EOF
   trajin $filename$a.mdcrd $x $x 1
   trajout pdbfit/a-2-$i.pdb pdb dumpq
EOF
^ no space before the E
```